# Jupyter lab, drag and drop images in Markdown cell: howto export as pdf?

Tags: image, pdf, drag-and-drop, jupyter

I use Jupyter lab on Windows, and use drag and drop to add images to a markdown cell. Very easy, and the image is stored in the .ipynb file, which make distribution of the notebook very easy using just a single file.
But if I do that, I don't seem to be able to export the notebook as pdf from the file menu. I got this:

"*dvipdfmx:fatal: Image inclusion failed. Could not find file: attachment:19ce03cd-0e1e-49f1-8cca-7dffa99e61c7.png*"

There is a workaround exporting it as html, and then opening it in chrome and then save it as pdf. But then there appear other problems in the pdf-version.
Is there a solution to this, where I can keep on using the drag-and-drop workflow?